# How to show the tooltip based on condition in angular 4?

Tags: angular, tooltip

For example, if you want display the tooltip only if button is disabled or an input box is disabled or any HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

Using material tooltip would be a good suggestion sense you're using angular.
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

To have a conditional material tooltip, you can either do:

```
<div matTooltip="This is a tooltip"
[matTooltipDisabled]="condition">TOOL TIP TEST</div>
```

where you place the condition of when you want the tooltip DISABLED in `matTooltipDisabled`

or you can do this (which I prefer):

```
<div [matTooltip]="condition ? 'This is a tooltip' : null">TOOL TIP TEST</div>
```

The logic here is that if the condition is met, then show the string, otherwise show null, which won't produce a tooltip.

I prefer the above because if you want dynamic tooltips or if there's complex logic for determining if the tooltip should be shown, you can even set this to be a function, that will either return a string or null.

Like so:

```
<div [matTooltip]="getToolTip()">TOOL TIP TEST</div>
```

The last option gives you less html code, and allows you to appropriately unit test the `getToolTip()` func.

Here's a stackblitz (I didn't make it, just found it) showing the 1st option, but I really think if conditional logic is just a bit complex, then go with the 3rd option I gave.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-tooltip-lnf3x6?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html

HOWEVER THERE'S AN IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT THIS!!!
It won't apply to disabled buttons. The focus on disabled buttons are handled in a way that doesn't allow tooltip. But that's fine, because you can just have a wrapper div around the button with the tooltip instead. same result.

Answer (score -2):

Use [attr.title] to show the tooltip based on condition.

```
<span class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
[attr.title]="Status == false? 'Fill the form to enable Download option' : 
null">
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="Status == false">Download</button>
</span>
```

do add the below jquery code in ngOninit() which helps to show the tooltip.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

Comment: I really don't like to combine jQuery code in my Angular components.
Why don't you use an angular tooltip component? PrimeNg provides a nice one: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip.

Comment: It may helps to who are already using jquery in their project.